# Can external multimedia files linked to pdf documents launch external applications in the macOS pdf-viewer Preview?

Tags: macos, latex, pdf-generation, beamer, pdf-viewer

I have generated a beamer pdf containing a link to an external player in order to play a sound. I am opening it with the macOS pdf viewer `preview` and when I hover the mouse pointer over the clickable text, the location of the .wav file is shown but when I click on the text nothing happens. Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\sound[externalviewer]{test}{sound.wav}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you try with another pdf viewer, e.g. adobe reader? Preview.app is known to not play nicely with the `multimedia` package

Comment: Yes, it works with adobe reader. is there a way to make it work with preview or perhaps some other pdf reader?

Comment: Sure, this also works with other pdf readers, for example `Skim.app`

Comment: I downloaded `Skim.app` using `brew` and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs Preview.app is known to not play nicely with the `multimedia` package.

I suggest to use another pdf viewer instead. For example, your code works fine with

- adobe reader
- skim